# How to transfer shader from regular to URP

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I found Shader how to roll surfaces and it workes with standard versions without pipe lines (link attached)... God will not forget your help if you direct me to repair the shader!

I can't put code here, because the limit doesn't allow using that many characters.

shader link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bLSL95RUMrje_nY1r-SZg-gWjA1hqFFl/view?usp=sharing

youtube shader link:
https://youtu.be/uO0RvxHk6LU?t=357

Unity material converter
Change from CGPROGRAMto HLSL
Add tag "RenderPipeline" = "UniversalPipeline"

Comment: Not the ideal answer but have you tried remaking it in shader graph

Comment: I guess you are right but I ll meet with that question first time and it sounds hard to me about shader creation ..